# The weakly convergence of a bounded sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

My question is the following:

> Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and $x_n$
>   be a bounded sequence in $\mathcal{H}$ such that $(Ax_n)$ converges strongly in
>   $\mathcal{H}$ to some element $y$ in $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose also that $A$ is injective, show that there exists an $x \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x$ and $Ax = y$.

I tried the Riesz representation and found that we can conclude that $Ax=y$ from the fact that $A$ is injective. The only issue here is to prove that there exists an $x \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x$. Need any hint or help.

Comment: Since your sequence is uniformly bounded in $\mathcal{H}$, you can use the Banach Alaoglu theorem (i.e. the weak compactness of balls) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Consequences

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks for commenting. Banach Alaoglu theorem says that every sequence in the closed unit ball has a weakly convergent subsequence whose limit belong to the ball, but how it concludes that the sequence $x_n$ is weakly convergencent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Banach Alaouglu, there exists a weakly convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ and an $x$, with $x_{n_k}\to x$ weakly. Then, for any $z\in H$, 
$$
\langle Ax_{n_k}-Ax,z\rangle=\langle A(x_{n_k}-x),z\rangle=\langle x_{n_k}-x,A^*z\rangle\xrightarrow[k]{}0.
$$
So $Ax_{n_k}\to Ax$ weakly. We also have $Ax_{n_k}\to y$, so $y=Ax$.

As $A$ is injective,
$$
\{0\}=\ker A=(\operatorname{ran} A^*)^\perp.
$$
So $A^*$ has dense range. For $z\in H$, 
$$\tag1
|\langle x_n-x,A^*z\rangle|=|\langle Ax_n-Ax,z\rangle|=|\langle Ax_n-y,z\rangle|\leq \|Ax_n-y\|\,\|z\|\xrightarrow[n]{}0. 
$$
Given any $w\in H$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $z\in H$ with $\|w-A^*z\|<\varepsilon$. Let $c=\sup\|x_n\|$. Then
$$
|\langle x_n-x,w\rangle|\leq|\langle x_n-x,A^*z\rangle|+|\langle x_n-x,w-A^*z\rangle|
\leq |\langle x_n-x,A^*z\rangle|+2c\varepsilon. 
$$
So, using $(1)$,
$$
\limsup_n|\langle x_n-x,w\rangle|\leq2c\varepsilon.
$$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we get that $\lim_n\langle x_n-x,w\rangle=0$, so $x_n\to x$ weakly.